# Doctrine override column name on embedded

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to override a column name for an embedded?
I want to maintain the customer bonus column name on database as `customer_earnings` instead of `customer_total`

```
Api\Comerce\Domain\Expenses:
    type: embeddable
    embedded:
        personalCommission:
            class: Shared\Domain\ValueObjects\AppliedPercentage
            columnPrefix: personal_
        customerBonus:
            attributeOverride:
                value:
                    column: customer_earnings
            class: Shared\Domain\ValueObjects\AppliedPercentage
            columnPrefix: customer_

Shared\Domain\ValueObjects\AppliedPercentage:
    type: embeddable
    fields:
        value:
            type: decimal
            nullable: true
            precision: 7
            scale: 2
            column: total 
        percentage:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
            options:
                unsigned: false
            column: percentage
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately doctrine does not support column override for embedded. You may only change the columnPrefix. If you still need separate column names, you may consider creating different classes for that purpose.